# Is this question about dissertationwriting.com on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness, specific-question

I found a website, http://dissertationwriting.com/, that claims to be a service to help students write theses and dissertations without breaking academic integrity. I'm skeptical, largely because as a master's degree student, I don't have enough experience to determine whether this company really is above-board. With this background, would this be an on-topic question for Academia.SE?

> Is http://dissertationwriting.com/ an ethical company? How can I tell for myself? How can I determine whether other, similar companies are honest or are paper mills for myself?

Comment: I'm not considering using this website's service one way or another, but they have some blog posts that I'm interested in. If the company isn't reputable, though, I'll look for advice elsewhere, which is why I'm interested in asking. I don't think my motivation for asking the question will affect its on-topicness, though.

Comment: Not an answer to whether it is on topic, but the schools listed in their [about us page](http://dissertationwriting.com/thesis-dissertation-services/) makes me think they are not legit.

Answer (score 5):

> Is http://dissertationwriting.com/ an ethical company?

See the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) article, section on "Can I ask questions about my specific situation?", where it says "As a general rule, if you're asking about a particular institution, course, or journal, it's likely your question is too limited in scope. Try to extract the fundamental question from the specific problem at hand."

You can, however, ask the general questions and give this company as an example:

> How can I tell for myself? How can I determine whether other, similar companies are honest or are paper mills for myself?

Yes, that is on topic. That is exactly the "fundamental question from the specific problem at hand."